# How do I use popover from Twitter Bootstrap to display checkboxes, div blocks, radios, images , any?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I use popover from Twitter Bootstrap to display checkboxes, div blocks, radios, images , any?

I need to make popover like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDAYf.jpg
Popover have to consist of div blocks etc. like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2kbl.jpg

Comment: <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Checkboxes placed here">Popover on bottom
</button><!-- Tooltip ends --

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `data-html="true"` to the element triggering the popover, bootstrap will then use jQuery `.html()` to insert the content into the dom. Be wary of `XSS` attacks using html in popovers.

Comment: I'm sorry , but can you give me an example?

Comment: ohhh thx you so much man! Could you help about adding close button there =)))) ?